# How to run laravel websockets in laragon?

Tags: laravel, websocket, laragon, laravel-websockets

**How to run laravel websockets in laragon?**

when run command to start websockets

```
php artisan websockets:serve
```

it's not working because

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji9Z6.jpg

and its still suck there

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcHH5.jpg

this is error on browser

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://nextlevelbot.test:6001/app/mykey?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.2&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my problem in SSL certifacates

I solve this problem by create SSL certificates for `nextlevelbot.test` and add them in folder in this path

`C:\laragon\etc\ssl\nextlevelbot.test`

and add path SSL certificates in `.env` file

```
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT =C:\laragon\etc\ssl\nextlevelbot.test\server.crt
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK =C:\laragon\etc\ssl\nextlevelbot.test\server.key
```

and edit path SSL certificates in config file for my project in this path

`C:\laragon\etc\nginx\sites-enabled\auto.nextlevelbot.test.conf`

```
ssl_certificate "C:/laragon/etc/ssl/nextlevelbot.test/server.crt";
ssl_certificate_key "C:/laragon/etc/ssl/nextlevelbot.test/server.key";
```

and `restart nginx` server in laragon

and run command `composer dumpautoload`

after that run command `php artisan websockets:serve`

after that work good :)

### Generate certificates for domain

I generate certificates by this scripts
https://gist.github.com/mindscms/721cf0968ddbbff5bad0c0b359d918e6
https://gist.github.com/mindscms/a7f3e7db0b6c7bfaaab56522ebed9042

1 - Download two files `make-cert.bat` and `cert-template.conf` from link above

2 - Create folder `cert` in `C:\laragon\bin\apache\YOUR_VIRSION_APACHE`
in my case `C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\cert`

3 - Put two file `make-cert.bat` and `cert-template.conf` in folder `cert`

4 - Run file `make-cert.bat` and answer the questions to generate certificates

5 - After finished script creates a folder with the name domain like`nextlevelbot.test`
`C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\cert\nextlevelbot.test`

6 - Inside this folder two files `server.crt` and `server.key`

Comment: How you got the certificates for `nextlevelbot.test` ?
I have only `C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.crt` for all projects.

Comment: I generate certificates by this script https://gist.github.com/mindscms/721cf0968ddbbff5bad0c0b359d918e6

Comment: I edit my answer to add hot to generate certificates

Comment: How's your websockets.php, broadcasting.php, and pusher.js (boostrap.js) setup?

Comment: I am using documentation when setup everything      
  https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/installation   
   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting

Answer (score 0):

That was helpful but not the exact reason
as this is a local cert, it needs permission

The easiest way ( oh its quirky )

1. Copy the failing wss link
   i.e. wss://example.test:3031/app/?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false
2. and replace the wss:// with https://

i.e.

https://example.test:3031/app/?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false

3. Open the link on another tab of same browser and accept  the certification on ssl prompt
4. try the websockets dashboard now, refresh and voila!

By the way, if you make any change to your nginx config for domain in laragon, you should remove the auto. prefix to avoid future auto overwrite by laragon